# Forbidden access 403 for some url using urllib2 python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I am trying to download the data from NSE India website. Data to be download is the zip file which I process after it downloaded.
I have sample code which downloads the files for dates after year 2016.

```
def start_download():

    directory = 'data'
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    try:
        #req = urllib2.Request("https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES//2000/JAN/cm01JAN2000bhav.csv.zip", headers=hdr)
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        req = urllib2.Request("https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES//2017/NOV/cm03NOV2017bhav.csv.zip", headers=hdr)
        file_url = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)
            file_name_obj = open(os.path.join(directory, "hello.zip"), 'wb')
            file_name_obj.write(file_url.read())
            file_name_obj.close()
        except IOError, e:
            print e
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

In the above code, when I use the url "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES//2017/NOV/cm03NOV2017bhav.csv.zip",it downloads the data. I also tried using Postman client, it downloads too.

When I use following url:https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES//2000/JAN/cm01JAN2000bhav.csv.zip, I get forbidden access 403 error in code as well as in Postman. When I paste this link in the chrome browser, then also issue exists.

But when go through link from this page "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm" and put `Report` as `Bhavcopy` and `date` as January 01, 2000, it successfully downloads the file *.csv.zip.

How do I fix this 403 forbidden error for commented url in sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your headers. 
Here is an example of how to do it and how to write the downloaded file using Python:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import shutil

link = 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES//2017/NOV/cm03NOV2017bhav.csv.zip'
header = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Host': 'www.nseindia.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

def download_file(link, file_name, length):
    try:
        req = Request(link, headers=header)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as writer:
            request = urlopen(req, timeout=3)
            shutil.copyfileobj(request, writer, length)
    except Exception as e:
        print('File cannot be downloaded:', e)
    finally:
        print('File downloaded with success!')

file_name = 'new_file.zip'
length = 1024
download_file(link, file_name, length)
```

Finally, you can check if the downloaded file using this method has the same SHA1 sum of the file downloaded with your browser:

File downloaded using Python:

```
> sha1sum new_file.zip 
daff49646d183636f590db6cbf32c93896179cb2  new_file.zip
```

File downloaded using Chromium:

```
> sha1sum cm03NOV2017bhav.csv.zip 
daff49646d183636f590db6cbf32c93896179cb2  cm03NOV2017bhav.csv.zip
```